# ADFS issued claims not available in WCF service deployed in SharePoint 2013

Tags: .net, wcf, sharepoint, adfs, claims-based-identity

I have a .NET 4.5.2 WCF service that I've deployed to SharePoint 2013 - and it works. Within the service method I need to access claims that have been set up in ADFS with the SharePoint application as the Relying Party.

I have confirmed those claims are returned by ADFS using [Jack Stromberg's excellent post](http://jackstromberg.com/2016/08/tutorial-using-fiddler-to-debug-saml-tokens-issued-from-adfs/).

In my service though, the method (code below) returns a single claim (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name) which is my logged identity. None of the three claims I've set up in the ADFS Relying Party Claim Rules come through.

```
public List<Claim> GetClaims()
{
    var p = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
    return p.Claims.ToList<Claim>();
}
```

I have ADFS tracing/debug on and well as SharePoint ULS. The latter shows the following when I access my service. I'm not sure what those 13 claims are, but I see none of them in the implementation (although I hope that 3 of them are the ones I set up in ADFS)

> Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=05.t|adfs
>   trusted root|, ClaimsCount=13

From other SO questions and various posts on the matter, I didn't see any additional configuration required between the WCF service and the SharePoint application to which it's deployed. But clearly I am missing something.

Comment: I suspect that you should configure Sharepoint to pass all claims from token to your wcf service....

Comment: @RomanAnanyev indeed, but as a SharePoint neophyte, I've not found exactly how to do that. There are a lot of articles over the past 10 years that touch on all this - mostly implying that the claims are 'just there' in IClaimsPrincipal (or ClaimsPrincipal now).